# React Native In App Browser does not have pop up in IOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-in-app-utils

I am implementing a React Native app with an in-app browsers using react-native-inappbrowser-reborn. The website I am trying to browse needs accesses to camera and mic of the users' computer. Normally, there would be a pop-up asking for user permissions. However, in IOS, the pop-up does not appear. It just does not appear and there isn't any errors. However, it works well in Android phones.

So, my question is whether I install it wrongly or this library does not handle that use-case at all?

Thank you guys.

Here is my Info.plist file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>en</string>
    <key>CFBundleDisplayName</key>
    <string>WebviewDemo</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>APPL</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleSignature</key>
    <string>????</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>localhost</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Camera Permission</string>
    <key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
    <string>Microphone Permission</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: can you share your `Info.plist` here? so we can see if the right permissions have been set.

Comment: thanks for the speedy response. I will now edit my post with Info.plist. Thanks sir. @kenmistry

Comment: @FreddyMo Did you manage to get it to work?